What if the Earth lost its gravitational force?
It's common to find such questions in textbooks, and generally the answer is that in the absence of other external forces (such as gravitational forces due to other stars and planets) a person standing on the earth would likely float upwards due to centrifugal force.
However, I can't wrap my head around the fact that according to Universal Law of Gravitation, $F = \dfrac{GMm}{r^2}$, the mass of Earth should become $0$, or that radius should become infinite.
In both cases shouldn't the person just remain in its original state as it would seem like the earth basically disappeared?
$0$ mass indicates that the Earth is no longer made of matter, and infinite radius would mean that in case of uniform distribution of mass, there is likely no mass per unit volume, meaning Earth has again vanished...
So shouldn't it mean the person would remain in its original position, and on application of an external force, it would move in that forces direction?

Something similar occurs in the short story "The Man Who Could Work Miracles" by H.G. Wells (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Could_Work_Miracles_(short_story)).  The narrator stops the Earth from rotating, which has catastrophic results.

Textbooks ask things like why people don't get hurled off the Earth due to the rotation of the Earth, which is a reasonable physics question.  However, any textbook asking what would happen if the Earth suddenly had no gravity is not teaching physics, it's teaching nonsense.

I don't quite understand what you're asking. Are you asking about the conditions for an object to exert no gravity, or the consequences of removing gravity from consideration (i.e. setting $G = 0$)? The two are completely different questions. You seem to be asking one in the title and the other in the body.

You are forgetting the fact that you are not stationary when standing on the Earth. It is spinning abouts it's axis, and you are spinning along with it. You are moving at a high speed right now.
Should the gravitational force from Earth suddenly disappear, then Earth would no longer hold you in this circular rotation. You would just keep the speed you have and continue in a straight line, tangentially away from from Earth. Just as how a stone, that you are swinging around in a string above your head, will fly off if you suddenly cut the string. Since the earth is still rotating in this thought experiment, then it will from your perspective look as though you are moving straight up from the ground.

Now, with that being said, this thought experiment would only work if earth was rigid. As if it was a giant steel ball.
Because if gravity suddenly disappeared as a physical concept from our universe, then not just you but everything would fly off. The soil and all along with you. It wouldn't make sense to say that you are lifted up off the ground, when the ground moves up as well (and very soon, everything would be a chaotic mess - but that would something for a What If-episode to dive into).

(As another answer also mentions, I'm not sure why you are using the law of gravitation to explain what would happen without gravity. Isn't the very premise that this law doesn't apply?)

The person would remain at their original position and velocity. The person is not stationary, however, due to the earth's rotation. Without the earth's gravity the person would continue in a strait line, which would carry them away from the earth's surface, which would rotate away beneath them

Since the "if" is impossible its not worth thinking about it. The if suggests that the law of gravitation is not valid, so mass has no gravitation effect, you could not use the law.

In such thought experiments, isn't it all right to use such laws in hypothetical situations? Cause coming up with new ideas such as mass having no effect gravitational effect complicates things even more...
